# Can Eclipse Double In Sacred Stones?

Tags: fire-emblem-the-sacred-stones

I've been thinking about the long-ranged tomes used in Fire Emblem games, and recently I've been wondering if the Eclipse tome can double attack. Eclipse, in Sacred Stones, brings your opponent to half health, rounded up. because of this, it has about 20 weight to prevent doubling. my question is, is Eclipse capable of doubling in the right circumstances, or is it programmed to only ever attack once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's a bit that can be set on particular weapons that determines whether or not the code checks for doubling.

> At 0x80290A6 we see
>   cmp r0, #0x3 Where r0 is the return call from a branch function that fetches the “Weapon Effect” of a weapon. This routine basically determines if you can double, and This will return false if this flag is set.

https://feuniverse.us/t/fe7-why-eclipse-cant-double-weapon-effect-0x3/275

08028560 - Byte of effect to check for when setting the menu display of attack to --
08028F3E - Byte of effect to check for when setting MT = 1/2 enemy HP(rounded up)
080290A6 - Byte of effect to check for when not allowing doubling

https://feuniverse.us/t/fe7-eclipse-documentation/579

While the damage is different between the 3 games (Eclipse reduces HP to 1 in FE6), the behavior is otherwise the same.

**In short - it doesn't matter how high your AS is. Certain weapons are programmed never to double. Eclipse is one of them.**

Comment: ok, but what does this mean?

Comment: @BlazingTrio It doesn't matter how high your speed is. Certain weapons are programmed never to double. Eclipse is one of them.

Comment: are there other weapons that can never double, or just Eclipse?

Comment: @BlazingTrio Not that I'm aware of, though practically you'll encounter that often with siege tomes / ballista.